# Do participants always have to click on Text Entry fields?

Tags: jquery, qualtrics

I am designing a Qualtrics survey which include Text Entry questions (there is a field in which the respondent has to enter a text). My problem is that each time the respondent loads a page with a Text Entry field, he has to click on it before he can type anything. Is there any way I can design the page so that the respondent can directly start typing, without having to click on the Text Entry field first?

In the same spirit, can I allow the respondent to get to the next question by pressing Enter?

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use `$('#firstInput').focus();` so that first element will be in focus when page loads.
2) Check what key was pressed:

```
$('#firstInput').keypress(function(){
    if (event.which == 13) {
        $('#secondInput').focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Where on Qualtrics shall I enter this?

Comment: @sophonax in `<script>` and wrap above code with `$(document).ready(function(){code});`